# How can handle tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I got an error while installing tensorflow 2
error is:

```
ERROR: tf-nightly 2.2.0.dev20200129 has requirement gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.2.2 which is incompatible.
```

[image]

and then I wrote pip install tf-nightly

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images

Comment: Not images, not links to images. Only text, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency needs to be fulfilled:
You may try doing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install gast==0.2.2
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: i see Requirement already up-to-date: gast in c:\........l\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.3.3) when i did.

Comment: Please show  the log after running pip install tensorflow, also make sure your pip is above 19.0.
nightly builds are usually unstable. the stable version requires you gast==0.2.2

Comment: My pip 20.0.2. 
C:\Users\MRX>pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                  Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mrx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)

Comment: @ozannyesiller Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: I did what you wrote. It works i installed tensorflow but when i wrote pip install tf-nightly i take 2 errors.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement gast==0.2.2, but you'll have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.                  ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 2.1.0 has requirement gast==0.2.2, but you'll have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.

Comment: @ozannyesiller There are 2 separate version dependency basis versions,
Nightlybuild requires 0.3.3 and stable  version requires 0.2.2

Comment: @SauravJoshi is there a fix for this?